# WSO2 registry automatically add 1.0.0 as a default version when importing a resource

Tags: wso2

I'm embarassed to see a default version (1.0.0) added to the namespaces of my resources  when importing a governance archive.

This happens even when versionResourcesOnChange property is set to false.

WSO2 governance registry version: 5.0.1

Any ideas ?